# Run executable jar with parameters from gradle

Tags: gradle

I wish to run executable jar from my gradle file. I have tied:

```
task runJar(dependsOn:jar) << {
javaexec {
    main="-jar"; args "C:/Development/AndroidStudioProjects/AndroidDev/Test.jar"
  }
}
```

But I get "Could not find property 'jar' on project ':MyProj"

I also tried:

```
task runScheduleReader << {
javaexec {
    main = "MainClass"
    classpath = "C:/Development/AndroidStudioProjects/AndroidDev/Test.jar"
    args('1')
  }
}
```

I am relatively new to groovy, can you please help me with that?
P.S... I put those function outside of android {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first code snippet `dependsOn` in task declaration means, that task `runJar` should be executed only after the `jar` task. Exception you get, says, that your current project doesn't have such a task. So, if you really don't need to execute `jar` task just before, you can simply not declere this task dependency:

```
task runJar() << {
    javaexec {
        main="-jar"; args "C:/Development/AndroidStudioProjects/AndroidDev/Test.jar"
    }
}
```

Though, this is a little bit strange case, when you have to execute some jar without relative path, this solution should work.

The second snippet should pass the jar as the argument too, but this time, it should be an arguments array, something like this:

```
task runScheduleReader() << {
  javaexec { 
    main="-jar";
    args = [
            "C:/Development/AndroidStudioProjects/AndroidDev/Test.jar",
            "1"
           ]
  } 
}
```